# Write result of evaluating python command in emacs buffer at point

Tags: python, emacs

How can I evaluate a line of Python code from emacs buffer and have the result be written to the buffer at my cursor?  I want to do something like in `haskell-mode` where you can type `C-u C-c C-t` and the type definition of whatever was at your cursor is inserted at your cursor.

So, if I selected and sent a region such as

`1 + 2`

from a `.py` buffer to the Python inferior process I would then see

`3
1 + 2`

in my `.py` buffer, ie. the `3` followed by a newline was inserted at point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert the result of a shell command at point we have `C-u M-!` (`shell-command`), so you can insert the result of a python command with `python -c "print 1 + 2"`.

To take the current line would need a bit of lisp. Here a very simple example.

```
(defun my-py-eval-insert-current-line ()
     "Eval the current line and insert its result."
     (interactive)    
     (setq cmd (read-from-minibuffer "Python cmd: " (format "python -c 'print %s'" (current-line))))
     (setq res (shell-command-to-string cmd))
     (insert res)
     )
```

with

```
(defun current-line ()
"returns the current line."
;; http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_all_about_lines.html
     (let (p1 p2 myLine)
       (setq p1 (line-beginning-position) )
       (setq p2 (line-end-position) )
       (setq myLine (buffer-substring-no-properties p1 p2))
       ))
```

I would rather look at pymacs for something serious.

ps: elisp functions: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Emacs_Lisp_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 1):

org-mode, i.e. org-babel provides a similar thing, which seems worth testing.

Current trunk of python-mode.el

https://launchpad.net/python-mode

offers an option `py-store-result-p`

When `t`, result is accessible in car of kill-ring - next yank inserts it.

You may define a command which reads `(car kill-ring)` for insert.

Also a feature request there should have some chances.